# EntityFramework can't see ConnectionString in the App.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, ef-code-first, connection-string

I am studying Code First EntityFramework together with ASP.Net MVC 3.
At first my trivial `EFDbContext` class was placed in the `WebUI` mvc project in a `Concrete` folder.

```
 public class EFDbContext : DbContext
 {
     public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
 }
```

And it was consumed through

```
 public class EFProductRepository : IProductRepository
 {
    private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

    public IQueryable<Product> Products
    {
        get
        {
            return context.Products;
        }
    }
 }
```

where

```
public interface IProductRepository
{
    IQueryable<Product> Products { get; }
}
```

So I added the following code to the root Web.config:

```
 <connectionStrings>
      <add name="WebUI.Concrete.EFDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=HORGH\SQLSERVER2008;Initial Catalog=SportStore;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

and **it worked**.

Then I decided to take it into a separate `Domain` Class Library project. There I have an App.config file. So I decided to move my connection string there, and it became to be:

```
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="Domain.Concrete.EFDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=HORGH\SQLSERVER2008;Initial Catalog=SportStore;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

But eventually **EF stopped seeing it**.

`EFProductRepository` and `EFDbContext` moved to the `Domain` project with their root folder `Concrete`. So the code calling the constructor is in `EFProductRepository`, i.e. in `Domain` project.

I tried to rename App.config to Web.Config; tried to return the connection string back to the Web.config of the `WebUI` project. It doesn't work neither.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to set your code-first class library as startup project when running migration command in package manager console?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*Class Library project* and *App.config file* don't mix.

The application's configuration file is always associated with an executable, or in the case of web.config, with a website.

Your DLL project cannot (and should not) have its own config file*.

Instead, configure the connection string along with your WebUI project.  You can have multiple connection string entries.

**There are actually ways to cause your DLL to in fact have its own config file.  NLog, for one, does that.  However, it is seldom a good idea.*

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Couldn't I understand myself that it was enough just to change the `name` in the original connectionstring to `Domain.Concrete.EFDbContext` and it would work...But besides you gave me a very good piece of info on the *.config issue. I didn't realize that! Thanks again!!!

Answer (score -1):

Use connection string name without `namespace`

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="EFDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=HORGH\SQLSERVER2008;Initial Catalog=SportStore;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: No, that won't work. Firstly, I tried this; secondly, you may have a look at the post marked as answer